# iOS Push Notifications: "Would like to receive Push Notifications" is never asked

Tags: ios, notifications, parse-platform, push

I have two apps that received Push Notifications.   I upgraded both to Xcode 6, and one works fine, the second one does not ever ask the user for permission to receive Push Notifications, nor does it receive the notifications.

I did update the code in the appDelegate to the new iOS 8 calls:

```
// register for push notification
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
                categories:nil]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

And I believe it is working correctly because didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is being called and I am getting a DeviceToken.

I have:

- Recreated (several times) my IDs and Provisioning profiles.
- I am testing this on the device, not the simulator
- I have tried to load it onto a iOS 8 AND iOS 7 device, neither works.
- Checked to make sure that the PN is being sent by PARSE (which I am using to create the PN's).  They are. And they are received on the second App.
- Pushed up the date on my phone, restarted it, and reinstalled the app (had deleted it first).

Also, the App is listed in the notifications section to receive notifications.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try deleting the app from your phone? If it is already there, then iOS has already prompted you for a decision and won't do it again.

Comment: Yes I did, many times.

Comment: Did your app display the Installation records required for Parse to link to the app?